# Bootstrap - 3 columns - what width do I create the images?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap (12 cols) and I would like 3 columns each with an image. I have no idea what the image widths should be. I have tried this: 
**70(col width) * 3colums + 60(30px gutter) = 270px.**

However if the page is not full width on a large monitor, the columns wrap.

What width should I create each image?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/our-work.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/galleries.png" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/news.png" class="img-responsive"  />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using col-md-4 for your columns that means that any viewport BELOW 992 pixels is going to change to full 12 column width. This also means the max-width you would probably need to make your images is based on the container size of the next smaller column width (col-sm-) which is 750. Then you minus the padding on the container = 720 pixels width.

```
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
```

You can go bigger to be safe as you are using img-responsive, but 720 should suffice.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If I make each image 720, 720 * 3 = way more wide than any container. Maybe I read your advice incorrectly. How wide (maximum) should I make each image? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. When you close up your browser below the medium viewport (col-md-), the container size will change to 750px and the columns stack one on top of each other and become full width of the row (12 columns).At this point the row is about the same width of the container. This based on the code you provided. It can also be seen on the jumbotron example from Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/  Again, 720 is based on maximum full-width of a column below the col-md size

Comment: @user995727 the `class="img-responsive"` will size-down your images if they are larger than the column. The column can reach 720px in width max. Therefore you make your images 720px width and let `img-responsive` make them fit